# removeAttr is partly working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a removeAttr when a page loads to overide inline css. It is partly working but isn't for everything.

Here is a JSfiddle to demo the problem https://jsfiddle.net/argilmour/efmxoL0h/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.text_default').children().removeAttr('style'); 
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working for everything"? Do you mean it's working for one of the `.text_default`s but not the rest? Could you try to elaborate more on what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change the JQuery selector. Change your JavaScript to this :

```
$('.text_default *').removeAttr('style');
```

According to your JSFiddle, you forgot to add JQuery.

Add this in your HTML code :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And in JSFiddle, add the library in the column on the left side of the web page.

Comment: Even with that fixed, the original problem (not all styles are being removed) persists.

Comment: Answer edited. thanks for telling me. (I didn't noticed)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this, `children` not match all descendant of `.text_default`. Otherwise, `find("*")` will match all children and its descendant.

```
$('.text_default').find("*").removeAttr('style');
```

**[Live a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/efmxoL0h/2/)**

Answer (score 3):

`.children()` only works on the *immediate* children of an element. If you want to remove the `style` attribute from *all* descendants, say:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.text_default').find('*').removeAttr('style'); 
});
```

or just:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.text_default *').removeAttr('style'); 
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.text_default *').removeAttr('style');
});
```

```css
.text_default {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-family: verdana;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="layout_default">
  <td class="layout_default" align="left" valign="middle">
    <div class="repcontent">
      <div class="text_default">
        <p dir="ltr" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial; font-size: 11px; text-align: justify; line-height: 1; margin-top: 5pt; margin-bottom: 0pt;"><span style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap; background-color: transparent;">Special conditions apply to the collection and holding of &quot;sensitive&quot; data. In this case you must obtain the </span>
          <span
          style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial; font-style: italic; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap; background-color: transparent;">specific</span><span style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Arial; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap; background-color: transparent;"> consent of the student/learner (ideally in writing). You may encounter this when gathering information before arranging work placements, outdoor activities or when taking photographs you intend to use later, perhaps for publicity or publication purposes. &quot;Sensitive Data&quot; has a special definition under the Data Protection Act and covers:</span>
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li><span style="font-family: Arial; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap; background-color: transparent;">race or ethnic origin </span>
          </li>
          <li><span style="font-family: Arial; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap; background-color: transparent;">political belief religious or other beliefs </span>
          </li>
          <li><span style="font-family: Arial; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap; background-color: transparent;">trade union membership (or otherwise) </span>
          </li>
          <li><span style="font-family: Arial; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap; background-color: transparent;">sexual life </span>
          </li>
          <li><span style="font-family: Arial; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap; background-color: transparent;">physical or mental health or condition (including pregnancy, learning or physical disability) </span>
          </li>
          <li><span style="font-family: Arial; vertical-align: baseline; white-space: pre-wrap; background-color: transparent;">actual or alleged criminal records or activities </span>&nbsp;</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```